# Font not downloading on cloudflare

Tags: css, html, cloudflare

I have Two servers, a local virtual machine and a external vps. both have simalar setups (Ubuntu LAMP), however the VPS is on cloudflare. They both run the same html & css code, however the VPS website doesn't download my font. See below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZgd8.png

What is The problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found my issue. It was in my deployment tools, the software script I created wasn't loading the fonts quite right. I applied a fix to my client, but utterly forgot the server.

Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for updating this:)

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the full font file from there. The only thing that I can think of is possibly Rocket Loader or Minify. Does turning those off change the behavior (check Rocket Loader first)? If using JavaScript or jQuery, Rocket Loader can potentially impact.

Comment: It Doesn't. It was the first thing I did.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly this is a MIME-type issue.

On your VPS  try creating a .htaccess file ath the root of your site with

```
AddType application/font-woff .woff
```

More info: http://is.gd/MZfuYr

Good luck!